using API4 to access a custom table in the database
If I create a new custom table directly in the database (mysql/wordpress), is there a way to access that table using the civicrm api (read and/or write)?

Ideally you should add an entity and not a custom table with SQL (see https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/step-by-step/create-entity/ or https://github.com/systopia/de.systopia.eck

Alternatively, if interacting with WordPress and CiviCRM thru a wordpress plugin, you can use wordpress $wpdb to access any tables in the db.

The short answer is no. I assume your table doesn't represent an entity or you would have just created it as an entity and then it would be available to the api.
You can always use CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery() - it's not technically api but it's used everywhere.
